# What is the best load testing tool?

Tags: asp.net, testing, load-testing

What is the best load testing tool for ASP.NET applications?

Comment: The question doesn't show any research effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fond of Siege for any HTTP load testing, or of course there's the classic ab.

Comment: -1.  Links to Siege and ab would be nice.

Comment: Can i generate random data for each request in ab ??

Answer (score 3):

Probably WCAT as it is MS and will give you shed load of Windows based metrics. [WCAT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231282)

However Jmeter (Java FOSS) is top notch [Apache Jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/)

And Selenium while not strictly a stress testing tool has many other testing features. [SeleniumHQ](http://seleniumhq.org/)

As i say WCAT if you are MS based is probably the best but worth casting your eye over Jmeter. Selenium is a FireFox plugin and does other testing that might interest you.

Comment: You actually can do load testing with Selenium: my company, BrowserMob, provides a service where you can generate 1000's of Selenium sessions. See http://browsermob.com

Comment: Doing load testing with Selenium is wasting resources.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Test Edition 2010 or any of the other SKU's that give you access to those tools.

The prices have just come out in Ed Glas's blog [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/edglas/archive/2010/02/07/vs-2010-sku-lineup-and-pricing-finalized.aspx).

This tool also appears in Visual Studio 2008.
The loadtesting tools that come with Visual Studio come with a great set of objects for manipulating tests. The test recording is great and Fiddler2 will record test as well.

It integrates well with your favorite ASP.Net dev environment... Okay, lame joke.

The results can be stored in a database with little effort and all perfmon stats are available for selection if required.

This is *the* tool for ASP.Net apps and I would use it for a Java site if I had to.

It is scalable in that Visual Studio itself can generate load for 250 virtual users (enough to bring your dev machine to it's knees). You can buy the licence for extra users to really get your "distributed denial of service" on.

Comment: VS2010 Ultimate is currently in beta and hence downloadable and free for several months.  I've used it extensively and I agree that it's very powerful for load and unit testing ASP.NET web apps.  WCAT can do it (though I had issues) but it's a toy compared to VS 2008 Team Suite Test Edition / VS 2010 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

There is one tool [here](http://www.webperformanceinc.com/load_testing/) that you can give a try.

Here is [a good article](http://www.webperformanceinc.com/library/reports/TestingAspDotNet/) that I've read recently.